# Solving $\int \frac{1}{6+(x+4)^2} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac{1}{6+(x+4)^2} dx = 6\int \frac{1}{1+\frac{(x+4)^2}{6}} dx$

Now $u=\frac{(x+4)}{\sqrt{6}}$ and $du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}dx$.

$6\int \frac{1}{1+\frac{(x+4)^2}{6}} dx=\frac{6}{\sqrt{6}}\int\ \frac{1}{1+u^2}=\frac{6}{\sqrt{6}}$ arctan$(u)$=$\frac{6}{\sqrt{6}}$ arctan$(\frac{(x+4)}{\sqrt{6}})+C$

However the result is $\frac{arctan(\frac{(x+4)}{\sqrt{6}})}{\sqrt{6}}+C$

Why is my result wrong? I can't see any mistake.

Comment: @haqnatural The result by OP is incorrect

Comment: First, you should divide 6 but not multiply 6 at the beginning; second, you should times $\sqrt{6}$ but not divide it at the second step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step is wrong $$ \frac{1}{6+(x+4)^2} \color{red}{\neq} \frac{6}{1+\frac{(x+4)^2}{6}}$$

Also, your substitution is wrong. You have substituted $$ \mathrm dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \mathrm du$$ Which actually is $$\mathrm du =\frac{1}{\sqrt 6} \mathrm dx$$
The given answer is correct.

Comment: Why is my first step incorrect?

Comment: @JohnKeeper If you have divided denominator by 6, then you must also divide numerator by 6, instead you have multiplied by 6.

Comment: Why am I so stupid sometimes?... jesus christ

Answer (score 2):

You can write it shortly as $$\int  \frac { 1 }{ 6+\left( x+4 \right) ^{ 2 } } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \int  \frac { \sqrt { 6 } d\left( \frac { x+4 }{ \sqrt { 6 }  }  \right)  }{ 1+{ \left( \frac { x+4 }{ \sqrt { 6 }  }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\frac { \sqrt { 6 }  }{ 6 } \arctan { \left( \frac { x+4 }{ \sqrt { 6 }  }  \right)  } +C$$

Comment: The answer by OP **is** wrong. Please look carefully.

Comment: Oh,it my carefulness ,thank you for point

Answer (score 2):

Start U-substitution:

$u$ = $x$+4 and $dx$= 1$dx$ $$\\$$
Making the integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{6+(u)^2} du$$ $$\\$$
Now do another U-substitution:

$u$ = $\sqrt6v$  and $du$= $\sqrt6 dv$ $$\\$$
Making the integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt6+(v^2+1)} dv$$ $$\\$$
Take out the constant:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt6}\int \frac{1}{(v^2+1)} dv$$
The integrand is a common integral. 
The integral of $\frac{1}{(v^2+1)} dv$ is $arctan(v)$.

So now you have:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt6} arctan(v)$

Don't forget to substitute back in $v$ and $u$.

$v$= $\frac{u}{\sqrt6}$ and $u$= $x$+4. $$\\$$
Your final answer is:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt6} arctan(\frac{x+4}{\sqrt6}) + C$$

Answer (score 1):

Anyway everyone should know that
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1a\arctan\frac xa.$$